# Java: Add a Global Mouse Listener

Tags: java, listener, applet, virtual-keyboard

I am developing a **virtual keyboard** using java applet. How do I set global mouse listener, so that I can get all mouse events inside my applet even if my applet is not the active window. And is there any way to get the focussed textbox globally, so that I can feed input to that textbox from my virtual keyboard. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to make a hook for that you need native code for windows machine take a look [here](http://www.jotschi.de/?p=90)